# Updating Column Value of Application Created from Spreadsheet in Oracle Apex Using SQL Query

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I created an application from a spreadsheet in Oracle APEX that contains a number of columns with information from different Oracle databases. There is a column in the application spreadsheet called "Database Size" that I would like to update in real-time in Oracle Apex. This column basically shows the database sizes of each and every Oracle database we look after. The below SQL query was used and executed on each and every database to get the database sizes of each database and they were manually populated in the spreadsheet.

```
select
  ( select sum(bytes)/1024/1024/1024 data_size from dba_data_files ) +
  ( select nvl(sum(bytes),0)/1024/1024/1024 temp_size from dba_temp_files ) +
  ( select sum(bytes)/1024/1024/1024 redo_size from sys.v_$log ) +
  ( select sum(BLOCK_SIZE*FILE_SIZE_BLKS)/1024/1024/1024 controlfile_size from v$controlfile) "Size in GB"
from
dual;
```

I would like to from a click of a button in the report Oracle Apex section to able to run this query for each database and update the "Database Size" column values instantly without having to manually go to each Oracle database server to run this query and update and the "Database Size" column values manually for each database on Oracle Apex.

Is this possible, if yes, how would I go about implementing this? I suppose the first step would be to create DB links from the Oracle APEX server that connects to all the different Oracle database servers?

N.B: Oracle Apex and ORDS is installed on one Server only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this:

- database links. Downside is that you'll manually have to maintain the list of databases that you need to poll
- rest endpoint (GET) on each database (but you need ORDS installed on all databases and also need to maintain the list of databases to poll. From 19c onwards those endpoints come with ORDS (https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/dbrst/rest-endpoints.html)
- rest endpoint that accepts a POST on the server that has apex installed and a job on each database that posts the data at regular intervals to the central server. (not real time, only at intervals). A bit of work to setup but you could package it and run the script on every new db.